# Transformation is not working in react

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

i am creating **svg shape** using **react components** and later on when i **drag** the image and change its **transformation** using react state it is not transforming the shape at that place. But when i do this transformation using ref it is working fine.

using ref means we are updating actual DOM which break the pattern of the react. according to react we use ref only the case when we have some spacial requirements(some this like this) etc.

Hope you under stand my question and the issue i am facing

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing your code. ;)